# Is it possible to get the rendering device for a given compositor in the windows composition api?

Tags: uwp, com, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I am wondering if it's possible to somehow call this API function for a given xaml control's compositor:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/apps/mt620066?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

What I am thinking is something along these lines:

```
    // Get the graphics device for the compositor
    auto compositor = Window::Current().Compositor();
    com_ptr<ICompositorInterop> comp_interop{ compositor.as<ICompositorInterop> };
    com_ptr<ICompositionGraphicsDevice> m_compgd{nullptr};
    comp_interop->GetGraphicsDevice(m_compgd.put()); // This doesn't actually exist.

    // Get the rendering device
    com_ptr<ICompositionGraphicsDeviceInterop> compgd_interop{m_compgd.as<ICompositionGraphicsDeviceInterop>()};
    com_ptr<IUnknown> m_device{ nullptr };
    check_hresult(
        compgd_interop->GetRenderingDevice(m_device.put())
    );
```

Except that obviously this doesnt work because there is no `GetGraphicsDevice` function available, only `CreateGraphicsDevice`.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Graphics and Animation - Windows Composition Turns 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590968.aspx)?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because in that demo Kenny creates the device himself and then uses it. I'm trying to get an existing device from a xaml control.

Comment: You could be able to get access to the underlying composition for a particular XAML element. You could do this using the [ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(UIElement)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview.getelementvisual#Windows_UI_Xaml_Hosting_ElementCompositionPreview_GetElementVisual_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_) method.